# How to do some actions for each file in a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a folder with files having .foo extension.

I need a batch file to execute some commands for each file in that folder having that extension.

**How should i do that?**

Seems I need a loop after getting the file list but I don't know how to do this in batch files... (I'm on Windows Xp but I guess the answer would be valid on other Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FOR %%F in (*.foo) DO command %%F
```

Operates the command `command` on with each filename as the first argument.

Remember that when in a batch file you must use `%%` where on the command line, the above would only use single `%`'s.

If you need the full pathname, or to get files recursively, use the `/R` switch of the for command.

Example:

```
C:\WINDOWS> FOR %F in (*.exe) DO @echo %F
```

explorer.exe
FramePkg.exe
gsk7bui.exe
hh.exe
IsUninst.exe
NOTEPAD.EXE
notepad1.exe
regedit.exe
slrundll.exe
TASKMAN.EXE
twunk_16.exe
twunk_32.exe
uninst.exe
winhelp.exe
winhlp32.exe

```
C:\WINDOWS> FOR /R %F in (*.exe) DO @echo %F
```

C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
C:\WINDOWS\FramePkg.exe
C:\WINDOWS\gsk7bui.exe
C:\WINDOWS\hh.exe
C:\WINDOWS\IsUninst.exe
C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE
C:\WINDOWS\notepad1.exe
C:\WINDOWS\regedit.exe
C:\WINDOWS\slrundll.exe
C:\WINDOWS\TASKMAN.EXE
C:\WINDOWS\twunk_16.exe
C:\WINDOWS\twunk_32.exe
C:\WINDOWS\uninst.exe
C:\WINDOWS\winhelp.exe
C:\WINDOWS\winhlp32.exe
... [lots more] ...
C:\WINDOWS\system32\accwiz.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\actmovie.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\ahui.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\alg.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\append.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\arp.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\asr_fmt.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\asr_ldm.exe
... [etc..]
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\accwiz.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\actmovie.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\admin.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\agentsvr.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\ahui.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\alg.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\append.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\arp.exe
... [and so forth..]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FOR loop to perform an action on each file

```
FOR %%parameter IN (set) DO command
```

Like

```
FOR %%G in ("C:\*") DO echo %%G
```

Comment: I should then replace the "C:\*" part by "myfolder\*.foo", right?

Comment: Correct.  If there are spaces in the path, I believe you have to use ^ in front of them as an escape character